# Azure Storage Service throws 403 forbidden error when trying to call REST API to clear queue messages

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage-queues

I'm trying to clear all azure storage queue message via Queue Service REST API.  I've verified that the code is correct, but it still returns a 403 forbidden error.  The "StorageSharedKey" and "StorageAccountName" are correct since I'm able to connect to the azure queue using those values in the connection string for the azure queue client.  The storage version I'm using is "2015-12-11".

Here is the code:

```
    internal void ClearStorageQueueMessages(string queueName)
    {
        const string requestMethod = "DELETE";
        string urlPath = $"{queueName}/messages";
        var dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var canonicalizedHeaders = $"x-ms-date:{dateInRfc1123Format}\nx-ms-version:{StorageVersion}";
        var canonicalizedResource = $"/{StorageAccountName}/{urlPath}";
        var uri = new Uri($"https://{StorageAccountName}.queue.core.windows.net/{urlPath}");
        var response = MakeDeleteRestCall(uri, requestMethod, dateInRfc1123Format, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource);
    }

    internal RestResponse MakeDeleteRestCall(Uri uri, string requestMethod, string dateInRfc1123Format, string canonicalizedHeaders,
        string canonicalizedResource)
    {
        var restResponse = new RestResponse();
        var stringToSign = $"{requestMethod}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{canonicalizedHeaders}\n{canonicalizedResource}";
        var authorizationHeader = CreateAuthorizationHeader(stringToSign);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = requestMethod;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateInRfc1123Format);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", StorageVersion);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
        //request.Accept = "application/atom+xml,application/xml";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        //request.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            restResponse.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (responseStream == null)
                return restResponse;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                restResponse.ReturnedContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return restResponse;
    }

    internal static string CreateAuthorizationHeader(string canonicalizedString)
    {
        string signature;

        using (var hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageSharedKey)))
        {
            var dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }

        var authorizationHeader = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}:{2}", StorageSharedKey,
            StorageAccountName, signature);

        return authorizationHeader;
    }
```

Comment: I'm launching this from my local pc, btw.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: Actually, it looks like I'm having the same 403 forbidden issue when I try to connect to the emulator, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the header Authorization. Please check the format according to the documentation:

> Authorization="[SharedKey|SharedKeyLite] :"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx

Your function adds the shared key in plain text instead of the authorization scheme "SharedKey" or "SharedKeyLite".

Comment: How else is the authorization scheme supposed to be built?  According to the documentation, the authorization is supposed to be built in this format:  {0} {1}:{2}, with the storage shared key in place of 0, storage account name in place of 1, and signature in place of 2.  And then that string is assigned to the "Authroization" header in the request.  All the examples I've seen do it this way.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you were on to something!  I needed to use the word "SharedKey" instead of the actual shared key value  Thanks a million!